# unknown at rule @include css(unknownAtRules) error while including @include in css file

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, angular-bootstrap, bootstrap-cards

I am trying to customize card columns by using Bootstrap 4 card layout. But why it is showing error if i am writing this code in my css file?

Error showing is in [VS code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWvLD.png):
unknown at rule @include css(unknownatrules)

HTML file

```
<div class="card-columns">
  <div class="card" *ngFor="let item of vision">
    <div class="card-header">{{item.heading}}</div>
    <carousel [showIndicators]="false">
      <slide *ngFor="let item of vision">
        <img class="card-img-top embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" [src]="item.img" alt="vision image">
      </slide>
    </carousel>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS file

```html
.card-columns {
  @include media-breakpoint-only(md) {
    column-count: 3;
  }
  @include media-breakpoint-only(lg) {
    column-count: 4;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

@include is a SASS feature not CSS feature.
Alternatively, you can turn the warning off by

```
  "css.lint.unknownAtRules": "ignore"
```

Reference : https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/53175

https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/issues/3190

Comment: I did this but the column size is not getting changed as per my code which I have written in css file

Comment: you can try if possible to use scss file.

Answer (score 6):

If you use scss, than "scss.lint.unknownAtRules": "ignore".

Answer (score 4):

The solution to this is almost always to install a plugin for your editor/IDE for PostCSS language support instead of regular CSS.

VS Code has a [PostCSS Language Support](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=csstools.postcss) plugin you can use that works great with morden CSS.

Answer (score 1):

From this [github issue](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/issues/3190), you need to add `stylelint-scss` to your `devDependencies` and in your `.stylelintrc` should have the following to turn off the warning.

```
{
  ...
  plugins: ["stylelint-scss"],
  "rules": {
    ...
    "at-rule-no-unknown": null,
    "scss/at-rule-no-unknown": true,
    ...
  }
}
```